# FreePascal: find lines where "= overload" is used

Tags: freepascal

I made generic list from `TFPGList<TnnItem>` and now compiler shows error (in Lazarus messages, for big code):

```
Error: Operator is not overloaded: "TnnItem" = "TnnItem"
```

but it don't show lines in source which uses this `= overload`. I want to remove this `=` usage lines. How to find them?

(fpc 3.0.0, Laz 1.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more pragmatic fix is to implement the overload for your custom type:

```
interface

  operator = (lhs: TnnItem; rhs: TnnItem): boolean;

implementation

  operator = (lhs: TnnItem; rhs: TnnItem): boolean;
  begin
    exit( (*TODO*) );
  end;
```

As the comparison may be done inside TFPGList.